# How to configure websocket in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

How to configure websocket to work with react js, currently i tried with 
npm install ws as well as 
npm install websocket
but I am not able to make request call

Comment: Can you show some code for your trial?

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask